# Why does my tmux theme not match the one I'm trying to install?

Tags: ssh, tmux, putty, theme

I am trying to install [this theme for tmux](https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux).

[image]

After all the steps specified in the instructions, I get this.

[image]

The color of the invitation is completely different, as well as all the "strokes" I have are square, and in the example they have the shape of triangles.

[image]

Also, if I am not connected, my terminal has just black and white colors.

What do I need to do to make my tmux theme match the one I'm trying to install?

Can I also customize my console separately from tmux?

*My server: Ubuntu 22:10 (I'm trying to configure tmux on it). I connect via ssh via Putty (Windows).*